# 2001 Toyota Sienna LE P0330 Error

Tags: toyota, sensor, sienna, knock

I don't know much about cars, so I might get some terms wrong.

My girlfriend drives an '01 Sienna LE and for a couple months the check engine light has been on. When I took the van to O'Reilly's and had them check the computer, it came back with the following error:

```
P0330: Knock Sensor 2 Circuit (Bank 2)
```

I've been working with a friend of mine to try and fix it, as he's extremely proficient with cars, but he's also somewhat hard to get a hold of sometimes. Things we've tried:

- Changing the fuses. Not all, but the ECM and a couple others.
- Using an octane booster and a higher grade gasoline (89 as compared to the usual 87).

Light is still on, and he said that now we'll need to take the intake off/apart to get the sensor which is inside near the cylinders. Is there anything else we can try? It's like $130 for a new sensor, plus mechanic fees. We just don't have the money for all of that.

Comment: Did you reset the code after changing the fuses? If not, I would reset the code and see if the lights comes back. You will need a scan tool to reset the code though. Part stores will not reset codes.

Comment: @rana I don't think I did, no. But the computer reset or something after the fuses came out and I had to do a drive to let it rescan the systems or whatever. I forgot what the term is exactly.

Comment: I don't think that is same as resetting the code. Either way, I don't think the issue is with the knock sensor it self. It could be some other sensor that is causing the engine to knock. Someone else with more wisdom will answer that. Unfortunately, you will have to get this fixed as knocking is bad for the engine.

Answer (score 2):

It is more than likely *not* the sensor. The problem lies in the circuit which *goes to the sensor*. Replacing the sensor is probably the last thing I'd do in this case.

In this case, I believe it is only a single wire you'd need to trace. It could also be the connector/connection at the sensor itself. In either case, it looks as though the intake manifold will need to come off in order to test the circuit or check the connection. Here is an image of the sensors with the intake off of the engine:

[image]

Breaks in the wire usually occur on the engine side of things, as that is where the most heat is located during operation (heat deteriorates things).